# passing value to destination controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am passing ID from UITABLEVIEWCONTROLLER to another UITABLEVIEWCONTROLLER but it throw the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setCityId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75225e0'
```

here us the prepareForSegue function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"cityPushToTab"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        featuredViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.cityId = [productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

}
```

the function did well before i call the cityId of featured controller. I have tried to logg the productKeys which print the correct values but it is terminating when I try to assign value to destination view controller object. please help.

Comment: I have a tabcontroller at the destination which have 4 tabs each with its own .m and .h file, i need the cityId for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `destViewController` is of class `featuredViewController` ? I'm sure it's not. The crash log tells it's a `UITabBarController`.

What I recommend is create a class that inherits from `UITabBarController`. I'll call it `MyTabBarViewController`. Set the class of your tab bar controller in your storyboard to this new class.

In `MyTabBarViewController.h`, create a property :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id cityId;
```

(note that cityId can be of any type you need, e.g. `NSString`, `NSNumber`, ...).

Then, change your `prepareForSegue` code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"cityPushToTab"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MyTabBarViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.cityId = [productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Next, in the .m files of the 4 view controllers that are in your tab bar, you can use this code to access `cityId` :

```
// Cast the viewcontroller's tab bar to your class
MyTabBarViewController *tabBarController = (MyTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController;

// Access your property
id cityId = tabBarController.cityId;
// You can test to see if it works by casting to an NSString and NSLog it
NSString *cityIdString = (NSString*) tabBarController.cityId;
NSLog (@"%@", cityIdString);
```